# WebSphere HttpSession not getting invalidated

Tags: java, http, session, websphere

It seems that the live http session count are in thousands and for some reason it seems session.invalidate is either not clearing the session or the "low-priority" thread is not claiming inactive sessions.

Please see output of live http session cout.

```
TIMESTAMP       Server      WAR FILE        Live Count
=========       ======      ========        ==========
2013-12-10_00:00    cib_bz_1    WD#K1.war           5253
```

In our logout servlet, we do call session.invalidate but it seems the http session still lingers on and is not cleared.

So I wanted to know:

- What can cause session.invalidate() not to invalidate the session? Is it possible if some other thread has refernece to same session it will not be invalidated?
- What can cause the low-priority thread that runs in Websphere not to invalidate and remove http session?

I would really appreciate your advise.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that the Tivoli PMI stats is incorrect and it is not taking into account the sessions that have been invalidated?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code is creating a new session during logout with the 'request.getSession(true)', or maybe you have some kind of .jsp with the following line:

```
<% @page session="true" %>
```

This will create a new Http session if there isn´t an existing one. This is one of the "classic reasons" for unwanted sessions.

To hunt down the problem enable session tracing. Apply the following trace string:
com.ibm.ws.session.*=all:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer*=all:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer*=all

Comment: Hello Robert,Thanks for the reply. Let us assume that is the case but if unwanted sessions are created then still they would time out at some point and should be re-claimed by WebSphere, no?

It seems the count reaches in 30,000, once it is restarted it is back to normal around 100-150 and keeps increasing almost a 1000 or so per day.

We did heap analysis and saw the 1000s of session in heap but majority of them showed isValid=false which means it was invalidated and the attributeNames and attributeValues are null.

Comment: Ok, then you must take a heap dump an analyze the GC root paths and try to find out which objects are referrers, i.e. keeping the sessions to stay "live" on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Found out it was a bug in WebSphere PMI stat

Comment: Here is the link to the issue description http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM66889 for reference